# How to convert string array to byte array in c#.net

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can any one help while creating storedprocedure with dynamicsql i am getting the below error and i am adding my code also.

create procedure getAreaRecords (@AreaID int) as begin set nocount on declare @sqlquery nvarchar(4000) declare @paramdefinitions nvarchar(2000) set @sqlquery='select AreaID,IsDeleted from areatable where IsDeleted<@AreaID' set @paramdefinitions='@AreaID int' exec sp_executesql @sqlquery,@paramdefinitions end

Error statements: Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure getRecords, Line 7 'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.

Comment: The only way to answer whether it is "correct" or not is to know what you want to do, and that's not clear at all. The above code will encode the 8th string of that array (and only that string) into bytes, using the ASCII encoding. Since the array only has 7 elements, the indexing part will fail. Why do you need to convert it to a byte array? If we knew why you wanted to do this, we might be more in a position capable of helping you.

Comment: You'll have a better chance of getting an answer if you make more effort to write your question.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert string array to object"?

Answer (score 2):

This will not give you the correct output.

If you want to convert every string item of `LogArray` into a byte array, then you have to loop over `LogArray` and convert each item one-by-one.

If you don't want to use a loop, you can use a lambda expression for it

for a array

```
string[] LogArray = { SyncKey, SyncType, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, noOfFiles, "null", Status, StatusMessage };
byte[][] LogArrayBytes = LogArray.Select(s => Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s)).ToList().ToArray();
```

OR for a list

```
string[] LogArray = { SyncKey, SyncType, StartDateTime, EndDateTime, noOfFiles, "null", Status, StatusMessage };
List<byte[]> LogArrayList = LogArray.Select(s => Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s)).ToList();
```

hope this helps...

Comment: Can u please tell how to convert  string array to object without loop in c#,i added above string array.

Comment: @user2852433 you need to convert every string to a byte array... Right ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick replay ,yes i need to convert byte array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert every string in `LogArray` to a byte array using the ASCII encoding, you would get an array of byte arrays; and here is how to do it:

```
byte[][] result = LogArray.Select(s => Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s)).ToArray();
```

the reverse operation:

```
string[] LogArray = result.Select(ba => Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ba)).ToArray();
```

Comment: Can any one help how to convert string array to object without loop in C#,i added above string array

Comment: Hi,after converting this stringarray  to byte array,again need to convert  back to string array,can you tell me please

Comment: @user2852433 check my edit. And you should have created another question.

Comment: @user2852433 "reply" or "answer" not replay.